# Razor View - Update DatePicker when another DatePicker is selected

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a case where I need to update a second datepicker with 365 days from the selected date on the first datepicker.
Is there a better way to do so except using Javascript?
I have searched a lot but could not find something clear.

Comment: I guess you have two options to choose from, one is going to server side which is not your case and second is using javascript or another js library like jQuery etc. I would prefer using some kind of js library for that. Personally I use bootstrap-datepicker which has those options configurable

Comment: which datepicker plugin you use

Comment: @Jay bootstrap datapicker

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj thank you for your answer.  :D
-E. Trupja

Comment: @eg16 you are welcome bish :p

Answer (score 0):

try this code in javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",     
        })
        .on('changeDate', function(ev){
            $(".datepicker2").datepicker({
            format: "yyyy-mm-dd",     
        });
        });
    });
```

you can use on changeDate method of bootstrap date picker in **ev** you can get your selected date

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with below javascript code :

```
$('#yourDatePickerId')     
     .datepicker({
         format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',        
         forceParse: false,
     }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
         var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
         $('#anotherDatePickerId').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);        
     });
```

In my case I require to set start date of another date picker you can add 365 days and set the another datepicker as desired dates.